# Accessing lower values of multilevel array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, list

I have a PHP array of objects and would like to get all the post_id values easily. I have looked into things like array_values and am not really sure what to do with this. Is the best way to just use a for loop and add each post_id to another array with all the post ids?

Thanks for the help!

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 70242
        [image_id] => 70244
        [large_image] => 0
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 70327
        [image_id] => 70339
        [large_image] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [post_id] => 70017
        [image_id] => 70212
        [large_image] => 1
    )
```

EDIT:
I am getting this array from a WordPress db call:

```
$q = <<<SQL
    SELECT post_id, image_id, large_image
    FROM $homepage_db
    ORDER BY position;
SQL;

$results = $wpdb->get_results($q);
```

And then `$results` is the array above

Comment: A `foreach` loop is easiest, or [`array_map()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), I don't think the newer [`array_column()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) would work for objects.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Did you mean `array_june()` :) ?

Comment: @BiVOC at least the link pointed to the right place.

Comment: One thing that may help is that I'm getting this array as output from a WordPress db query, I'll edit that into my post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a `foreach` loop

```
foreach($result_object as $item){

    $post_id_array[] = $item->post_id;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

using `foreach`

```
$post_ids = array();
foreach($arr as $e) {
  $post_ids[] = $e->post_id;
}
```

using `array_map`

```
$post_ids = array_map('get_post_id', $arr);
function get_post_id($e) {
  return $e->post_id;
}
```

I prefer `foreach` in this case

Answer (score 3):

Easy. Use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-map.php). Code below; used JSON for your data to test & demonstrate the concept while retaining your example structure:

```
//  Set the JSON string for this example.
$json_string = <<<EOT
[
    {
        "post_id": "70242",
        "image_id": "70244",
        "large_image": "0"
    },
    {
        "post_id": "70327",
        "image_id": "70339",
        "large_image": "1"
    },
    {
        "post_id": "70017",
        "image_id": "70212",
        "large_image": "1"
    }
]
EOT;

// Decode the JSON string as any array.
$json_string_decoded = json_decode($json_string);

// Use array_map to return an array telling you what items have 'distancia'.
$results = array_map(function($value) {
    return $value->post_id;
  }, $json_string_decoded);

// Dump the array to view the contents.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the dumped output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 70242
    [1] => 70327
    [2] => 70017
)
```

Comment: Mate - the OP's example is an array of objects

Comment: omit the second `true` param from `json_decode()` for a comparable structure and substitute `return $value->post_id;`

Comment: This seems overly complicated when I can just use a foreach loop

Comment: @JakeGould It works because the function is mapped over the outer array (which is really an array) -- doesn't really matter what is passed into the function, as they would be scalars in a 1D array or anything else... You cannot, unfortunately, run `array_map()` over all the properties of an object however.