# How do I iterate through a JSON array of arrays in CodeIgniter/PHP?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, shopify

My view is displaying the JSON response. My end goal is to display specific product attributes as well as sub-arrays like product variants within a table.

In RoR I'm accustomed to getting object attributes by doing something like

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<%= product.handle %>
<% end %>
```

And it's this basic functionality I’m trying to replicate. I’m not sure if I’m doing something wrong with the `json_decode` method, or if I’m introducing a syntax error when I try to display a particular attribute of an object within the array, or if something else is going on as this is my first time using PHP.

**controllers/products.php:**

```
class Products extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $token = $this->session->userdata('token');
    $this->load->library('shopify', array('shop' => 'boxcetech', 'token' => $token));
    $this->load->view('products');
}
}
```

**views/products.php**

```
$products = $this->shopify->getProducts(); // call the getProducts function from my custom Shopify library
```

**libraries/shopify.php**

```
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

$response = json_decode($response, true);

return $response;
```

**the json**

```
    {
    "products": [
        {
            "body_html": "ats descrip",
            "created_at": "2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00",
            "handle": "all-terrain-sound",
            "id": 303615011,
            "product_type": "Electronics",
            "published_at": "2014-06-04T15:19:51-04:00",
            "published_scope": "global",
            "template_suffix": null,
            "title": "All-Terrain Sound",
            "updated_at": "2014-06-12T10:00:02-04:00",
            "vendor": "BOXCeTECH",
            "tags": "",
            "variants": [
                {
                    "barcode": null,
                    "compare_at_price": null,
                    "created_at": "2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00",
                    "fulfillment_service": "manual",
                    "grams": 513,
                    "id": 708832835,
                    "inventory_management": null,
                    "inventory_policy": "deny",
                    "option1": "Default Title",
                    "option2": null,
                    "option3": null,
                    "position": 1,
                    "price": "69.95",
                    "product_id": 303615011,
                    "requires_shipping": true,
                    "sku": "ats-1",
                    "taxable": true,
                    "title": "Default Title",
                    "updated_at": "2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00",
                    "inventory_quantity": 0,
                    "old_inventory_quantity": 0
                }
            ],
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 359550119,
                    "name": "Title",
                    "position": 1,
                    "product_id": 303615011
                }
            ],
            "images": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00",
                    "id": 726055931,
                    "position": 1,
                    "product_id": 303615011,
                    "updated_at": "2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00",
                    "src": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0525/6049/products/ATS-front.png?v=1401909942"
                }
            ],
            "image": {
                "created_at": "2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00",
                "id": 726055931,
                "position": 1,
                "product_id": 303615011,
                "updated_at": "2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00",
                "src": "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0525/6049/products/ATS-front.png?v=1401909942"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**output in browser at localhost:8080/products**

```
    array (
  'products' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'body_html' => 'ats descrip',
      'created_at' => '2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00',
      'handle' => 'all-terrain-sound',
      'id' => 303615011,
      'product_type' => 'Electronics',
      'published_at' => '2014-06-04T15:19:51-04:00',
      'published_scope' => 'global',
      'template_suffix' => NULL,
      'title' => 'All-Terrain Sound',
      'updated_at' => '2014-06-12T10:00:02-04:00',
      'vendor' => 'BOXCeTECH',
      'tags' => '',
      'variants' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'barcode' => NULL,
          'compare_at_price' => NULL,
          'created_at' => '2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00',
          'fulfillment_service' => 'manual',
          'grams' => 513,
          'id' => 708832835,
          'inventory_management' => NULL,
          'inventory_policy' => 'deny',
          'option1' => 'Default Title',
          'option2' => NULL,
          'option3' => NULL,
          'position' => 1,
          'price' => '69.95',
          'product_id' => 303615011,
          'requires_shipping' => true,
          'sku' => 'ats-1',
          'taxable' => true,
          'title' => 'Default Title',
          'updated_at' => '2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00',
          'inventory_quantity' => 0,
          'old_inventory_quantity' => 0,
        ),
      ),
      'options' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 359550119,
          'name' => 'Title',
          'position' => 1,
          'product_id' => 303615011,
        ),
      ),
      'images' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'created_at' => '2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00',
          'id' => 726055931,
          'position' => 1,
          'product_id' => 303615011,
          'updated_at' => '2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00',
          'src' => 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0525/6049/products/ATS-front.png?v=1401909942',
        ),
      ),
      'image' => 
      array (
        'created_at' => '2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00',
        'id' => 726055931,
        'position' => 1,
        'product_id' => 303615011,
        'updated_at' => '2014-06-04T15:25:42-04:00',
        'src' => 'http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0525/6049/products/ATS-front.png?v=1401909942',
      ),
    ),
    etc....
  ),
)
```

Comment: What is the issue / what's your question? I see the array, it's not a json array, it's just an array.  You want to iterate through it? What data do you want to output/capture?

Comment: "I'm re-writing a Shopify APP in PHP (originally in Rails) and am stuck at the simple task of listing the "handle" attribute of each of my 3 Products within a foreach loop." So I just want to output each product's Handle in the view. i.e. "all-terrain-sound", "splash-shower-tunes-premium", "splash-shower-tunes" as strings.

Comment: Edited - Please let me know if I can provide more clarity.

Comment: it's a PHP array. you work through it like any OTHER array. just because it came from a json string doesn't make it magically different.

Comment: @MarcB I'm not accustomed to handling json responses. The reason I specified I initially did this with Rails is that the plug-and-play nature of the Shopify API Gem made it insanely easy to access objects and attributes the same way I'm used to doing basic db queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($products['products'] as $product){
     echo $product['handle']; //will print each product handle
     $product_handles[] = $product['handle'] //will create array of product handles
}
```

Comment: Same "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error. I'm manually building an array for $products right now to see if perhaps there's some issue with the value that's being passed to $products from the library.

Comment: Ok, it's just a question of getting to the right level in the array, it's hard to diagnose with the formatting of the array that you posted.  But one step would be doing a `print_r($product)` in the foreach loop and seeing what prints there.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the values. You can do this using [`array_map`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.array-map.php) or [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). The value of `$test_data` is the exact JSON sample you posted to your original question:

```
// Decode the source JSON as an array.
$products_array = json_decode($test_data, true);

// Example with array_map. 
function get_product_handles ($data){
  return $data['handle'];
}
$product_handles_map = array_map('get_product_handles', $products_array['products']);

// Example with foreach. 
$product_handles_array = array();
foreach ($products_array['products'] as $product_key => $product_value) {
  $product_handles_array[] = $product_value['handle'];
}

// Outout via array_map. 
echo '<b>Outout via array_map:</b>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($product_handles_map);
echo '</pre>';

// Outout via foreach. 
echo '<b>Outout via foreach:</b>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($product_handles_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

And here is the output of that:

```
Outout via array_map:
Array
(
    [0] => all-terrain-sound
)
Outout via foreach:
Array
(
    [0] => all-terrain-sound
)
```

Comment: Haha...didn't we do this dance yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175441/accessing-lower-values-of-multilevel-array-in-php

Comment: This was the same approach I tried initially but I get the error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: @MattLangan I just updated my answer...it's `$products['products']`